# How do i pin point a null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

i used the custom feed activity code in my application i used it inside a fragment instead of the main Activity.However it   gave me an error" there an  expected {" after puuting the code in the method the application is not responding while ir post a null pointer exception

Comment: Use the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/logcat.html) tool to search for the error. It will pinpoint it for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors